# How to join to the same table multiple times?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have two tables, "hierarchy_table" and "name_table".

The hierarchy table contains an object which has multiple parents and children. Each parent and child is referenced by id.

```
|  object_id  |  parent_id_1  |  parent_id_2  |  child_id_1  |  child_id_2  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1234    |      9999     |      9567     |     5555     |     5556     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each object id in the hierarchy_table has an entry in the name_table:

```
|  name_id  |    name    |
--------------------------
|   1234    |   ABCD     |
--------------------------
|   9999    |   ZYXW     |
--------------------------
| ...
```

How do I join each id in the hierarchy_table to the name_table multiple times so that I can have a result where every name is populated?

Like this:

```
|   object    |   parent_1    |   parent_2    |   child_1    |   child_2    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     ABCD    |      ZYXW     |      BBBB     |     CCCC     |     DDDD     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note:  the table names in the example are just for clarity / simplicity, the real names have proper names.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `hierarchy_table` has 5 columns that all reference the `name_table`, so you need 5 joins. It may be better to use `LEFT` joins instead of `INNER`, in case some of these columns are nullable and you still want the rows returned:

```
SELECT 
    o.name  AS object, 
    p1.name AS parent_1, 
    p2.name AS parent_2, 
    c1.name AS child_1,  
    c2.name AS child_2 
FROM 
    hierarchy_table AS h
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS o   ON h.object_id   = o.name_id
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS p1  ON h.parent_id_1 = p1.name_id  
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS p2  ON h.parent_id_2 = p2.name_id
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS c1  ON h.child_id_1  = c1.name_id 
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS c2  ON h.child_id_2  = c2.name_id ;
```

Comment: Yes, so columns are nullable, so I do need the left join. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason, I just wasn't getting a grasp of aliasing until this answer.  It may be worth noting that this won't work in MS Access (maybe others).  I was trying to do something very similar and I kept getting a syntax error.  Access requires nesting of Joins with ().

Comment: @doubleJ yes, Access is notorious for this need of extra parentheses whenever there are more than 1 joins in the `FROM`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the `AS` in the join clauses appears to be optional in postgres. But maybe that's bad practice?

Comment: @Phlucious true, it's optional in all flavours of SQL (with very few exceptions). And yes, I think it's good practice to use it, both in SELECT list and the FROM clause

Answer (score 3):

You can use alias name for tables involved in query.

```
select b.name object, c.name parent_1, d.name parent_2 
from hierarchy_table a, name_table b, name_table c, name_table d
where a.object_id = b.name_id 
  and a.parent_id_1 = c.name_id 
  and a.parent_id_2 = d.name_id
```

Comment: You'd better not use the old-style (old means more than 20 years) joins.  The ANSI syntax is more readable and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

**TL&DR:** Alias should be used when you want to join to the same table multiple times

**Rational:**

In Postgres, typically people join one column in one table to another column in a different table. This was brilliant from a design perspective as the normal use case.  When you want to join additional columns you will need to use aliases (best practice).

**HOWTO:**

When performing an INNER JOIN, make sure to add an AS clause along with the name.

**Example**

```
INNER JOIN ipaddresses as child_address ON ipaddress_relations.ipaddress_id = child_address.ipaddressid
```

If you notice the 'accepted' answer does this above.

```
SELECT 
    o.name  AS object, 
    p1.name AS parent_1, 
    p2.name AS parent_2, 
    c1.name AS child_1,  
    c2.name AS child_2 
FROM 
    hierarchy_table AS h
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS o   ON h.object_id   = o.name_id
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS p1  ON h.parent_id_1 = p1.name_id  
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS p2  ON h.parent_id_2 = p2.name_id
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS c1  ON h.child_id_1  = c1.name_id 
  LEFT JOIN name_table AS c2  ON h.child_id_2  = c2.name_id ;
```